# I am Getting this error "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED" .how do i solve it?

Tags: android, manifest

I am getting this error.Please help me. I tried to solve this but i could not.Thanks in advance.This is my Manifest file. Please tell what are the things that i need to change or add.Please explain why ? Explanation would be preferred.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Puzzle1024.angry2048"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="Puzzle1024.angry2048.app.MainGame"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="Puzzle1024.angry2048.Screen"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

system package name should contain only lower case characters.

```
  package="Puzzle1024.angry2048"
```

P is caps.

Comment: Can package name carry numbers?

Comment: @MehediHassan yes, i do not think it will make any issues

Answer (score -1):

In such a case usually do following:

1. check the manifest-file for syntax errors
2. clean your project (e.g. build->clean or delete /bin-folder and sometimes /gen-folder)
3. go to the project/package explorer
4. right-click on the manifest-file
5. VALIDATE!

Everything should be fine now.

Comment: I got the solution..Thanks any way..Thank you for responding.